# Get user input for month and year to populate cells with dates of that month and year in excel

Tags: excel, date

i want to take two inputs from user Year and month and then populate the cells with the dates of that month and year in excel.

for example:

Enter year:2017

Enter month:Jan

Date
1/1/2017
1/2/2017
1/3/2017
1/4/2017
.
.
.
.

the cells should auto populate when the month and year is entered.
thanks for suggestions in advance.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and how it didn't work.

Comment: i have surfed the Internet for the solutions and most of the suggest to click on the "+" icon and drag until you get the desired date. 
whereas i want it to me automatic, just put in the month and year and boom! the dates are auto-populated. :P

Answer (score 0):

Without context, it's not clear what you need.  Do you want the user to enter the data in dialog boxes or enter the data into two cells?  What format will the user be expected to enter the dates in?  For example, should January be entered as "Jan", "January", "1" etc.?  You probably just need to have 31 formulas set up that reference the input cells, but you need to specify exactly how that input is handled first.

EDIT:

That was meant to be a comment, not an answer, so here is my actual answer:

In cell A1, set up a data validation rule.  The rule should be a list with the source given as "Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec" or the longer form if you prefer.  Now when you try to edit this cell you have the option of selecting from a drop-down list of months.

[image]

If you want to limit the year range as well, you can do something similar in cell B1.  Just create comma-separated list of valid years in the source field.

Enter the numbers 1 to 31 in cells A3 to A33 then enter this formula in cell B3:

```
"=DATEVALUE(A3&"-"&$A$1&"-"&$B$1)"
```

Autofill/copy that down to B33.  The DateValue function takes the calculated string (for example "13-Feb-2017") and converts it to a date which you can then format any way you want.  Note that this will produce the error "#VALUE!" if either of the input cells are blank or if the choosen month doesn't have 31 days, but you can modify it to your own needs.

Comment: i want the user to input the data into two cells, and the format is not really imp, but if to be specified "jan", "january" is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assume this.

Cell b1 tooks input as month, create a name range rng

cell d1 tooks input as year, create a name range yearsamp

column I and J have this, with a formula in j3.

=IF(MOD(yearsamp,4)=0,29,28)

`month  days 
1   31
2   29
3   31
4   30
5   31
6   30
7   31
8   31
9   30
10  31
11  30
12  31`

name above cell range as monthdays

use this formula in A2 and fill

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(mnth,monthdays,mnth,FALSE)>=ROW(A2)-1,DATE(yearsamp,mnth,ROW(A1)),"N/A")
```

This is another option to achieve this

You can use this formula also.set up as said above.

on first field for 1st date enter this on A2

```
=DATE(d1,MATCH(b1,I1:I12,0),1)
```

On A3 write this forula and fill

```
=IF(ROW(a2)-1<VLOOKUP(mnth,mnthdays,2,FALSE),a2+1,"")
```

As you have 31 cells with formula it return errors when the month day count are less than 31 but this formula show those as blank without errors.